# error of header trying to register in laravel: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

when trying to register, gave me this error :

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected
> vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:359

[image]

and this is the line of the error:

```
foreach ($this->headers->allPreserveCaseWithoutCookies() as $name => $values) {
    $replace = 0 === strcasecmp($name, 'Content-Type');
    
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        header($name.': '.$value, $replace, $this->statusCode);   
    }
    
}
```

what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-detected

Comment: its not the same error @MustafaPoya